# How do I import a csv-file into a table via Drupal?

Tags: importing-exporting, database

I would like to import a csv into a table via Drupal. I use Drupal 7.

I create a content type 'Import', which contains a File field to upload a file to the server (destination: sites / default / files / import / *)

When I validate my form content 'Import', I will wish to make a db_query ()

```
db_query ("
LOAD DATA INFILE '$ csv_filename' INTO TABLE $ temp_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES ");
```

$ csv_filename, I test the relative and absolute way, but drupal tells me it can not find the file. I even give the rights to the file to test 777 but it is not ca.

$ temp_table is my table, it already exists in the database.

You would know the procedure and a use case that works for this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this quite what you're looking for, but the [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) module can import CSV content into nodes. Perhaps it could help...

> Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.
>
> - One-off imports and periodic aggregation of content
> - Import or aggregate RSS/Atom feeds
> - Import or aggregate CSV files
> - Import or aggregate OPML files
> - PubSubHubbub support
> - Create nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records from
>   import
> - Extensible to import any other kind of content
> - Granular mapping of input elements to Drupal content elements
> - Exportable configurations
> - Batched import for large files

Comment: Thank you for the info.
Made in, I had to matter *. Csv file that I sort to update the nodes.
I go through reading the file and adding line by line.